# Scroll bottom sheet seamlessly when scrolling a Flatlist within a custom bottom sheet

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I'm creating a custom react native bottom sheet using `GestureDetector` from `react-native-gesture-handler` and i want to pass a `child` `Flatlist` to the sheet. but having an issue with the scrolling. The scroll of the `flatlist` consumes the gesture handler of the sheet and the sheet does not move up instead the flatlist scrolls in place. I want the sheet to behave normally when attempting to scroll the `flatlist` area the sheet scrolls instead. I want it so that the flat list scrolls to the maximum top destination and then for the flat list to carry on scrolling in one continues `scroll` gesture. i tired to use an `Animated.flatlist` from `react-native-reanimated` and make use of the `onScroll` `event`. but I'am still not able to achieve the desired outcome.

Code I have attempted:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Dimensions, FlatList, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Gesture, GestureDetector, GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import Animated, {
  Extrapolate,
  interpolate,
  useAnimatedRef,
  useAnimatedScrollHandler,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withSpring,
} from "react-native-reanimated";
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get("window");

const data = [
  { id: "1", title: "Item 1" },
  { id: "2", title: "Item 2" },
  { id: "3", title: "Item 3" },
  { id: "4", title: "Item 4" },
  { id: "5", title: "Item 5" },
  { id: "6", title: "Item 6" },
  { id: "7", title: "Item 7" },
  { id: "8", title: "Item 8" },
  { id: "9", title: "Item 9" },
  { id: "10", title: "Item 10" },
  { id: "11", title: "Item 11" },
  { id: "12", title: "Item 12" },
  { id: "13", title: "Item 13" },
  { id: "14", title: "Item 14" },
  { id: "15", title: "Item 15" },
  { id: "16", title: "Item 16" },
  { id: "17", title: "Item 17" },
  { id: "18", title: "Item 18" },
  { id: "19", title: "Item 19" },
  { id: "20", title: "Item 20" },
  { id: "21", title: "Item 21" },
  { id: "22", title: "Item 22" },
  { id: "23", title: "Item 23" },
  { id: "24", title: "Item 24" },
  { id: "25", title: "Item 25" },
];

export const MyBottomSheet: React.FC = () => {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  // const listRef = useAnimatedRef<FlatList>();
  const listRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);

  const MAX_TRANSLATE_Y = -SCREEN_HEIGHT + insets.top;

  const translationY = useSharedValue(0);
  const context = useSharedValue({ y: 0 });

  const scrollTo = useCallback(
    (destination: number) => {
      "worklet";
      translationY.value = withSpring(destination, { damping: 50 });
    },
    [translationY],
  );

  const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
    .onStart(() => {
      context.value = { y: translationY.value };
    })
    .onUpdate((event) => {
      translationY.value = event.translationY + context.value.y;
      translationY.value = Math.max(translationY.value, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
    })
    .onEnd(() => {
      if (translationY.value - SCREEN_HEIGHT + 200) {
        scrollTo(-SCREEN_HEIGHT + 200);
      }

      if (translationY.value < -SCREEN_HEIGHT + 100) {
        scrollTo(MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
      }
    });

  const reanimatedBottomSheetStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const borderRadius = interpolate(translationY.value, [MAX_TRANSLATE_Y + insets.top, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y], [20, 0], Extrapolate.CLAMP);

    if (translationY.value === MAX_TRANSLATE_Y) {
      listRef.current?.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: true });
    }
    return {
      borderRadius,
      transform: [{ translateY: translationY.value }],
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollTo(-SCREEN_HEIGHT + 200);
  }, [listRef, scrollTo]);

  const Item = ({ title }) => (
    <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  const onScroll = useAnimatedScrollHandler((event) => {
    const offsetY = event.contentOffset.y;
    // scrollTo(-offsetY + -SCREEN_HEIGHT + 200);
  });

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[reanimatedBottomSheetStyle, { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT, top: SCREEN_HEIGHT, borderRadius: 25, backgroundColor: "white" }]}
        >
          <Animated.FlatList
            style={{ margin: 20, marginTop: 50 }}
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            onScroll={onScroll}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </GestureDetector>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};
```

Comment: @collinsmarra not tried since. i just used gorhom/bottom-sheet in the end https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gorhom/bottom-sheet